# Is it possible to add a watermark on to a JPG without re-compression?

Tags: php, image-processing, jpeg, watermark, lossless-compression

It seems to be logical that it should be impossible to add a watermark to an JPG image without re-compressing the image when saving it as an JPG. Can someone confirm this?

The question is generally related to PHP, but I don't think the server language makes a difference to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, you have to recode. The way to do is to ensure that the component sampling and the quantization tables are the same. That will minimize any recoding distortion.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, depending on your requirements. If:

- your watermark consists of blocks that are 8x8 pixels, and
- these blocks can be applied 100% opaque to your image, and
- your image is compressed using these 8x8 Minimum Coded Units

You could theoratically replace only the 8x8 blocks where the watermark is going to be.

Then you won't need to recompress any MCUs

See also here for more information of how to process JPEG without recompressing: http://www.betterjpeg.com/lossless-rotation.htm